# adding an image as an equation with number

Tags: equations

I had troubles writing a dynamic-programming formulas using Latex (they were too long and I was not able to break them into lines and indent them adequately using Latex), which finally made we write them in PowerPoint and add them as PNG files using `\begin{figure}[H]`.

All the formulas in the paper I am writing, are enumerated, i.e., they appear with a reference number that looks like `(i)`, as I wrote them within an `equation` block.

The problem, of course, is that the dynamic-programming formulas that I included using `figure` blocks are not enumerated like the real LaTeX equations are.

Is there a way to make LaTeX wrap my figures with equation blocks, so that it also enumerates the image-based formulas?

Alternatively, is there a way to produce a LaTeX equation that looks like this? (Made this in PowerPoint and indented by separating into different objects that I could move to wherever I wanted):
[image]

Comment: don't put them in `\begin{figure}` put them in `\begin{equation}` but using powerpoint generated png should be the absolute last option!!!

Comment: Thanks! I agree. But I must have had an option to break the lines and indent each line as much as I wanted, in order to produce a readable formula, which I was not able to figure out how to implement.

Comment: Using the `figure` environment to insert an image is not necessary in this case. `\includegraphics` can stand on its own, just like `tabular` doesn't need a `table` environment.

Comment: You're missing an opening `{` in the formula. Where should that be?

Comment: even if you use powerpoint to generate the equation (which I would never do) then saving it as a png bitmap rather than a scalable format like pdf makes a bad display even worse.

Comment: @AgvaniaRekuva: Perhaps you should post the question as to how to typeset the equation as you desire directly in LaTeX instead.

Comment: @Werner thank you for finding this mistake :) . The `}` should be omitted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a visual system to indent by dragging means it is impossible or at least hard to get consistent indentation throughout the document, for example here having cost to the left of the : makes it hard to see if the cost expression is in the scope of the for all i.

Using a bitmap format for moving the formula to tex makes the already poor typesetting much worse as bitmap formats really render poorly in pdf, especially if you zoom in or out.

You could use a setting such as the one below (if you really want grad and scaled to be italic, that could be arranged as well.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator\grad{grad}
\DeclareMathOperator\scaled{scaled}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
  \forall i \colon{}&\mathit{MinIndices}[0] \leq i\leq\mathit{MaxIndices}[0]\\
&\mathit{cost}[0,i]=\lVert\grad(r[0:\mathit{Anchors}[0]])\\
&\quad-\grad(\scaled(w[0:i],\mathit{Lengths}[0]))\rVert
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply include the image within the equation, however it is probably easier to write the formulas directly in tex.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

A short example how you could write multiline equations:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
 a  & = b \notag \\
        & - c
\end{align}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can, with `\includegraphics`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx} 

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{matrix}\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{schoolgirlsnotebook}\end{matrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]